# Alamofire_SwiftyJSONCommandを導入するとfailed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11がでる

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

xcodeのプロジェクトにcocoapodsでalamofire、swiftyjson、alamofire-swiftyjsonの3つのライブラリをインストールしたのですが、alamofire-swiftyjson.swiftでビルドエラーとなってしまいます。
エラーメッセージは下記のとおりです。
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

下記のサイトの方法も試しましたが、解決しませんでした。
http://qiita.com/nakamurau1@github/items/754871a161e56233d0ba